# im writing a python for loop in which the program asks a question, and if the user inputs a certain answer, the program will display a certain message

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

here is the code:

```
MyArray = []
question = []
for i in range(3):
    question = input("what is 2+2 ")
    if question != '2':
       print('wrong')
    elif question != 'yes':
       print('wrong ')
    MyArray.append(question)

print(MyArray)
```

I entered both 2 and yes, but it the program kept saying 'wrong' each time

bear with me since I'm new to programming

Answer (score 1):

When you input 2, it is not 'yes', so print 'wrong' in elif
When you input yes, it is not '2', so print 'wrong' in if

Comment: ah i see, feel kinda stupid now but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are printing wrong if the answer is not `2`, and printing wrong if the answer is not `yes`. The answer can not be both `2` and `yes` at the same time.

You can do something like this:

```
MyArray = []
question = []
for i in range(3):
    answer = input("what is 2+2 ")
    if answer == '4':
       print('right')
    else:
       print('wrong ')
    MyArray.append(answer)

print(MyArray)
```

now it prints right if the answer is `4`, and wrong in other cases.
You will probably want a list with right answers for each question.

Something like:

```
# variables
user_answers = []
right_answers = ['1','2','4']
questions = ["what is 1 + 0?","What is 1 + 1?", "what is 2 + 2 ?"]
score = 0

# ask questions
for i in range(len(questions)):
    answer = input(questions[i])
    if answer == right_answers[i]:
       print('right')
       score+=1
    else:
       print('wrong')
    user_answers.append(answer)

print(f"your answers were: {user_answers}, and your score is {score}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if you input '2', the first condition (if question != '2') isn't met. so it pass to the second condition (elif question != 'yes') and this condition is met ('2' != 'yes') so it print the second 'wrong'.
When you input 'yes' the first condition (if question != '2') is met ('yes' != '2') so it print the first 'wrong'.

To solve this you need to reverse your condition and work with == instead of !=.

```
MyArray = []
question = []
for i in range(3):
    question = input("what is 2+2 ")
    if question == '2':
       pass # or print something 
    elif question == 'yes':
        pass # or print something 
    else:
       print('wrong')
    MyArray.append(question)

print(MyArray)
```